# Unable to call JavaScript method based on button element "id"

Tags: javascript, dom, button, event-handling

I am following a tutorial from Head First Javascript. In the tutorial, the `showBlogs()` method is called via the following html code

HTML button
`<input type="button" id="showall" value="Show all blog entries" onclick="showBlogs();" />`

```
function showBlogs(numberOfEntries){

        //sort the blogs in reverse chronological order (most recent first)
        blogs.sort(function(blog1, blog2){
            return blog2.date - blog1.date;
        })

        //set the number of entires if non specified
        if(!numberOfEntries){
            numberOfEntries = blogs.length;
        }

        //set blog entries
        var currenetBlog = 0; blogListHTML = "";
        while(currenetBlog < blogs.length && currenetBlog < numberOfEntries){
            blogListHTML += blogs[currenetBlog].toHTML(currenetBlog % 2 == 0); 
            currenetBlog++;
        }

        //display blog entries
        blogsDOM.innerHTML = blogListHTML;

    }
```

However, when I create another button and access it via javascript and call the same method with the event handler - nothing happens.

Button
`<button type="button" id="showAllBlogs">Show All Posts</button>`

Access Button within Javascript
`const showBlogsButton = document.getElementById('showAllBlogs');`

Call the `showBlogs` method
`showBlogsButton.addEventListener('click', showBlogs);`

I did try creating another function say 'foo()' and I called `foo()` with the new button and I was able to invoke the method. But when I call the `showBlogs()` method, nothing happens.

```
JAVASCRIPT CODE



`
//dom elements
    const blogsDOM = document.getElementById('blog');
    const query = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    const searchButton = document.getElementById('searchButton');
    const showBlogsButton = document.getElementById('showAllBlogs');


    // Constructor
    function Blog(body, dateString){
        this.body = body;
        this.date = new Date(dateString);

        this.toString = function(){
            return this.date.getMonth() + '/' + this.date.getDate() + '/' + this.date.getFullYear() + '/' + 
                   this.body;
        };

        this.toHTML = function(highlight){
            var htmlPost = "";

            //determine to highlight post
            htmlPost += highlight ? "<p style='background-color: #EEEEEE'>" : "<p>";

            //generate formatted html
            htmlPost += this.date.getMonth() + '/' + this.date.getDate() + '/' + this.date.getFullYear() + '/' + 
            this.body + "</p>";

            //return html
            return htmlPost;
        };

        this.containsText = function(text){
            return this.body.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        };

    }

    //Array of blogs
    var blogs = [
        new Blog("Got the new cube I ordered", "01/25/1986"),
        new Blog("This new cube works just fine", "02/22/2000"),
        new Blog("This is going to be the third one", "03/23/2005"),
        new Blog("This is the final one", "03/21/2020")
    ]

    blogs.sort(function(blog1, blog2){ return blog2.date - blog1.date; })

    function getDaysBetweenDates(date1, date2){
        var daysBetween = (date2 - date1) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
        return Math.round(daysBetween);
    }

    function formatDate(date){
        return date.getDay() + '/' +  date.getMonth() + '/' + date.getYear();
    }

    function searchForPost(event){        
        let matchingBlogs = [];
        event.preventDefault();
        const searchQuery = query.value;

        blogs.forEach(blog =>{
            if(blog.body.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) > -1){
                matchingBlogs.push(blog);
            }
        } )

        showBlogs(matchingBlogs.length, matchingBlogs);
    }

    //show list of blog
    function showBlogs(numberOfEntries, blogsToShow = blogs){

        //sort the blogs in reverse chronological order (most recent first)
        blogs.sort(function(blog1, blog2){
            return blog2.date - blog1.date;
        })

        //set the number of entires if non specified
        if(!numberOfEntries){
            numberOfEntries = blogs.length;
        }

        //set blog entries
        var currenetBlog = 0; blogListHTML = "";
        while(currenetBlog < blogs.length && currenetBlog < numberOfEntries){
            blogListHTML += blogs[currenetBlog].toHTML(currenetBlog % 2 == 0); 
            currenetBlog++;
        }

        //display blog entries
        blogsDOM.innerHTML = blogListHTML;

    }

    searchButton.addEventListener('click', searchForPost);
    showBlogsButton.addEventListener('click', showBlogs);`

HTML CODE

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <h3>Youtube - the Blog for Cube puzzlers</h3>

    <div class="search-container">
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search for a blog"/>
        <button type="button" id="searchButton">Search the blog</button>
    </div>
    <div id="blog"></div>
    <input type="button" id="showall" value="Show all blog entries" onclick="showBlogs();" />
    <button type="button" id="showAllBlogs">Show All Posts</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Can you include the full code as a snippet? I want to know the chronology of your calls.